# Nil events in IPS reports today

Tags: ids

The IPS reports have one or two events minimum every day so far. But today there were no events, both in DC1 and DC2 reports. I am wondering if this possible? How come on a particular day nobody attaked us? Has anyone experienced similar situation?

Comment: We don't have a statistical model of attacks for your type of site so we cannot provide a definitive answer, but I don't see why it wouldn't happen, with a random statistical variable, that occasionally you get a count of 0 events on a day. It seems perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

Script kiddies need holidays too.
Seriously, how about the answer "coincidence"? If there are usually one or two per day, it´s not that hard to believe that some days have 0. Just random background noise in the internet.

Or maybe there was a single person repeatedly trying to get into your net. In this case, things happen to people. Computer broke; hospital, drinking the whole day because girlfriend left...

Or *maybe* someone got into your net and thought it would be a good idea to delete the log.
Maybe. If the missing attack is the only problem, I wouldn´t panic. If it lets you sleep better, check some more things, and if everything is ok, forget it.

Comment: A lot of times FUD (fear, uncertainty, doubt) reports get a lot of attention. It is good someone is giving advice based upon common sense. One thing I am curios about: OP is getting just 1-2 IPS events per day. We get like ~100 per hour.

Comment: @void_in my thoughts exactly, if 1-2 is normal, then I might suspect a misconfigured IPS.

Comment: 1-2 events is rare but it does happens somedays. Otherwise normally on an average we see around 20 -30 events per day!